# Difference between mutate() and using $ to add a column in dplyr and tidyerse in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

Suppose I want to create a new column in a tibble. I don't understand the difference between using mutate and just creating a new column using $. For example,

```
df <- mutate(df, seven = 7)
```

vs

```
df$seven <- 7
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

The point of `mutate` is to add columns. The advantage is that you can use multiple `dplyr` verbs in sequence with the `pipe` (`%>%`) operator:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(seven=7, height=8) %>% 
  filter(height!=7) %>% 
  select(seven, height)
```

For many (including myself), this is much easier to read than base `R`.